# How long does it take to smoke a chicken?

Tags: chicken, cooking-time, smoking

I have tried to smoke chicken twice now and both times have taken at least 6 hours. I put the chicken (about 6 lbs) in my smoker with about 40 coals and add some wood. I also periodically add coals and wood.

Does it really take 6 hours to smoke a chicken of that size?

Comment: are you aiming for pulled chicken or sliceable chicken?

Answer (score 10):

While cooking low and slow has its advantages, 6 hours is a bit too long. You should be able to complete a 6 pound chicken in 1 1/2 - 2 hours @ 275°F [135°C].

Some things to remember that might help you out:

1. You are going for an internal temp of 160°F [70°C] in the breast
   meat and 170°F [75°C] at the thigh.
2. Every time you open the smoker you are allowing an ENORMOUS amount
   of heat to escape, this prolongs the cooking time. *(If I were to
   bet, it would be that you are checking it too often)*
3. Almost all the flavor your going to achieve from smoking is reached
   in the first 30 minutes. You may want to smoke it for 30minute - 1
   hour and then transfer it to a 275°F oven if you are having issues
   maintaining the heat in your smoker.

Comment: No 3 for the win.

Answer (score 2):

From experience, I know that the longer you smoke anything, the better smoke flavour you will get.

Personally, I inject my meat first. The next thing is to maintain a temperature between 200°F & 250°F. I always check my wood and baste every half hour. I add coals every hour as needed.

With poultry, I remove it from the smoker while it is still a little undercooked and finish it in a covered roasting pan (with the rest of the marinade I used to baste) in the oven for about 45 minutes. This will keep your chicken or turkey from drying out.

I would smoke a 5 lb. chicken for 3 or 4 hours (130°F), then finish in the at 400°F oven until it reaches 170°F (approximately 45 minutes). It should turn out moist and full of flavour.

Answer (score 1):

I smoked a 6lb chicken the other day... At 250° for 5.5 hours, after the first hour I was spraying it with Chicken broth. It was juicy and tender...smoke flavored all through.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I smoke a 6 lb chicken for 2 hours at 275 degrees but I also brine the bird for 3-4 hours before smoking. The brining keeps the chicken nice and moist. I use two trays of dry wood chips during the smoking period. Cherry wood is my preferred  wood choice.  I use the master built electric smoker.